# How to store multi-selected row with color highlighted in javascript model table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing Issue related background colour change on submit(table row) need to be there(store) when i
go by modal (like pagination concept it's one page have some limited number of record) next and previous button, but code written like that it's every time refresh the page  when i submit next and previous button . How I can Solve this ??

and 2nd when I select row it data come in list before submit when i remove row it not remove the colour from that table row, please help me any suggestion is welcome ??? below is my code ..

**Code**

```
function popRoleNext(){
  $("#roleAddTable > tr").remove();
  current=current+incremVal;
  popRole();
 }
 function popRolePrev(){
 $("#roleAddTable > tr").remove();  
current=current-incremVal;
  popRole();
 }
```

**Html Part Of Table**

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="roleAddTableMain">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <!-- <th class="col-sm-5">Role Id</th> -->
           <th class="col-sm-6">Role Description</th>              
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="roleAddTable">

       </tbody>
    </table>
         </div>
```

**Script part of table to retrieve data**

```
function popRole(){      
     var roleAddTableValue="";

 for(var i=current;i<current+incremVal;i++){ 
     if(i>=arrCount) {//hide next button
        $("#popRoleNextBtn").prop('disabled', true);
     break;
        }else if(arrCount==(current+incremVal)) {
            $("#popRoleNextBtn").prop('disabled', true);
            //break;
        }
        else{
         $("#popRoleNextBtn").prop('disabled', false);
        } 

     if(current<=0){
     $("#popRolePrevBtn").prop('disabled', true);

     }else{

        $("#popRolePrevBtn").prop('disabled', false);

     }
     var arrValuesSub = arrValues[i].split(':');

     roleAddTableValue = roleAddTableValue+"<tr>";

           roleAddTableValue = roleAddTableValue+"<td id='"+arrValuesSub[0]+"' class='modelRoleId'>"+arrValuesSub[1]+"</td>";

              roleAddTableValue = roleAddTableValue+"</tr>";
  }
 $("#roleAddTable").append(roleAddTableValue);
 }
```

Comment: I don't see any buttons in the html or anywhere that `popRoleNext()` gets called. You probably have a form also but that isn't shown either. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl : Thanks for your reply.. i am calling that popRoleNext() function using this code : $("#popRolePrevBtn").on("click",function(){
        popRolePrev();
        });
       $("#popRoleNextBtn").on("click",function(){
        popRoleNext();
        });